# How to set true to list of data in my Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently , Im getting an arraylist (type String) from my adapter that is doing some selection logic.

Now, I want to push those values to my Firebase database, that is working fine , but its pushing my like this

[image]

Instead, I need it to be push like this

```
USERID1 : true;
USERID2 : true;
...
```

my code

```
mDatabase.child("myawesomenode").child(teamID).setValue(mAdapter.getSelectionList());
```

I have tried doing a map this way

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(mAdapter.getSelectionList().toString(),true);
```

and set the data with `updateChildren()` , but is not even sending the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you have a `Collection` called "myawesomenode" and you are trying to create a `Document` inside this `Collection` with an id that is the `teamID`. Inside that `Document` you want to have a list or map of "UserIds" linked to a boolean value.

Personally, I think it's easier to use POJOs when making Firebase Database transactions. You can create a "Team" object (or whatever you want to name it) and inside that object you can have a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` variable called "teamStatus", for example.  Then you can just push a change to the "teamStatus" map via the "Team" document selected by it's `teamID` value to just modify the "userStatus" `HashMap` as needed. You would be manually managing the whole Map though.

```
class Team {
    public Map<String, Boolean> teamStatus;
}

myawesomenode
  - <thatTeamIDValue>
    - teamStatus
      -<key0>:<value0>
      -<key1>:<value1>
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
class Team {
    public List<MemberStatus> memberStatusList;
    public String someOtherString;
}

class MemberStatus {
    public String id;
    public boolean isRegistered;
    public String name;
    /// other things
}

myawesomenode
  - <thatTeamIDValue>
    - memberStatusList
      - 0
        - id:<idValue>
        - isRegistered:true
        - name:DaName  
      - 1
        - id:<idValue>
        - isRegistered:false
        - name:DaOtherName  
    -someOtherString:SomeOtherValue
```

... and then you can just query against that structure instead.

It's really about how you want to structure your no-sql database.  Take a look at some documentation about Firebase no-sql and it'll give you a better idea about how to structure your data to fit your exact needs.

Edit:  The POJO style also allows you to easily send data out to update and convert the JSON string response directly into a usable form.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer ! I need to stick to the first option that is having a map since i need to update all the values and not overwrite them, since a team can have multiple players and by adding one I dont want to replace all the current ones, I think that storing index 0, 1, 2 and so on to save data is not good for structure purposes

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you found a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the follow

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getSelectedDataArray().size(); i++) {
                map.put(mAdapter.getSelectedDataArray().get(i),true);

mDatabase.child("myawesomenode").child(teamID).updateChildren(map);

}
```